# Grails filter stats insert performance

Tags: sql, performance, grails, groovy, before-filter

I have a filter in grails to capture all controller requests and insert a row into the database with the controllerName, actionName, userId, date, and guid.  This works fine, but I would like to find a way to increase the performance.  Right now it takes ~100 milliseconds to do all this with 70-80ms of that time creating a statement.  I've used both a domain object insert, groovy Sql, and raw java connection/statement.  Is there any faster way to improve the performance of inserting a single record within a filter?  Alternatively, is there a different pattern that can be used for the inserts?  Code (using groovy SQL) Below:

```
class StatsFilters {

def grailsApplication
def dataSource
def filters =
{
    logStats(controller:'*', action:'*')
    {
        before = {
            if(controllerName == null || actionName == null)
            {
                return true
            }
            def logValue = grailsApplication.config.statsLogging
            if(logValue.equalsIgnoreCase("on") && session?.user?.uid != null & session?.user?.uid != "")
            {
                try{

                    def start = System.currentTimeMillis()
                    Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)
                    def userId = session.user.uid
                    final String uuid = "I" + UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-","");
                    String insert = "insert into STATS(ID, CONTROLLER, ACTION, MODIFIED_DATE, USER_ID) values ('${uuid}','${controllerName}','${actionName}',SYSDATE,'${userId}')"
                    sql.execute(insert)
                    sql.close()
                    def end = System.currentTimeMillis()
                    def total = end - start
                    println("total " + total)
                }
                catch(e)
                {
                    log.error("Stats failed to save with exception " + e.getStackTrace())
                    return true
                }
            }
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

}

And my current data source

```
dataSource {

pooled = true
dialect="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect"
properties {
    maxActive = 50
    maxIdle = 10
    initialSize = 10
    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 1800000
    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 1800000
    maxWait = 10000
    validationQuery = "select * from resource_check"
    testWhileIdle = true
    numTestsPerEvictionRun = 3
    testOnBorrow = true
    testOnReturn = true
}
//loggingSql = true
```

}

----------------------Solution-------------------------

The solution was to simply spawn a thread and do the stats save.  This way user response time isn't impacted, but the save is done in near real time.  The number of users in this application (corporate internal, limited user group) doesn't merit anything more robust.

```
void saveStatData(def controllerName, def actionName, def userId)
{
    Thread.start{
        Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)
        final String uuid = "I" + UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-","");
        String insert = "insert into STATS(ID, CONTROLLER, ACTION, MODIFIED_DATE, USER_ID) values ('${uuid}','${controllerName}','${actionName}',SYSDATE,'${userId}')"
        sql.execute(insert)
        sql.close()
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd be interested to know if using the Grails Executor plugin might be better, Executors are meant to be Thread's 'done right', so perhaps there are performance and reliability gains to be had there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better pattern is not to insert the row in the filter instead just add a record to some list and flush the list into database regularly by asynchronous job (using Quartz plugin for example).

You could loose some data if application crashes, but if you schedule the job to run often (like every x minutes), it should not be an issue.

Comment: Losing data would be an issue because this keeps track of exactly what is happening in the app.  If the application crashes, that is the exact time when we will want this information.  That said, I think I will work on an asynchronous solution, just not in a batch mode.  I'll post it if I get it working.